# How to prevent AdBlocker from stopping my Facebook Tracking PIxel

Tags: facebook, analytics, adblock, facebook-pixel

I'm currently using a Facebook Tracking pixel to determine which leads convert to the TY page but I've noticed that AdBlock is stopping all pixels from firing. Here is an example of my code

```
    
    
      !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
      {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
      n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
      if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
      n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
      'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
      fbq('init', '{your-pixel-id-goes-here}');
      fbq('track', 'PageView');
    
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={your-pixel-id-goes-here}&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Any advice on how to prevent AdBlocker from stopping this?
Thanks

Comment: If you could circumvent my ad- and tracker blocking measures, it would mean they would not be working correctly.

Comment: The purpose of the tracking is for monitoring FB ad numbers, not to showcase ads. I understand it's built to prevent this but it hard for tracking leads coming in from this specific place.